# Is it possible to format paragraph in flutter?

Tags: flutter, paragraph

Is it possible to format paragraphs (alignment, indent, spacing) in flutter?

Like I do in MS Word:

[image]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    home: SafeArea(child: Scaffold(body: Text('first line\nsecond line'))),
  ));
}
```

Comment: format paragraph means?

Comment: @MunsifAli a part of text between `\n`

Answer (score 1):

Use Expanded Widget to move it on second Line and use Text Align to Align the text

```
Expanded(child: Text("first line second line",textAlign: TextAlign.center,)),
```

Comment: tried it but the text is not aligned. Probably because of `expanded` should be a child of `Column`. And what about first line indent and spacing?

Answer (score 0):

See i don't see any difference between alignment and indent(can help you if you explain me) so that can changed with `textAlign` property of `Text` widget. And about spacing im assuming you're referring to letter spacing that can manipulated with `letterSpacing` parameter of `TextStyle`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      body: Expanded(
          child: Text(
        "First line\nsecond line",
        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 5),
      )),
    )),
  ));
}
```

changing them can produce below result

[image: a]

[image: b]

And if you want different text stying too, than you can refer to [RichText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html)
widget which can produce different text styling for individual paragraphs.

Comment: please see the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```dart
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
      child: Text("Paragraph 1"),
    ),
    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
      child: Text("Paragraph 2"),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: there is no first line indent, justification and spacing between paragraphs. And I am looking for a simple way to format all these parameters (to avoid splitting text by paragraphs to different `Text` widget)